# How to loop through and capture each selected item in an Access List Box?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I am trying to loop through a multiselect list box and pass each value to a function that runs a stored procedure, I am just not sure how to do it.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub cmdBegin_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim selected(89) As String
Dim item As Variant

With Me.lstSmartSheet
    For Each item In selected()
        If Me.lstSmartSheet.selected(item) Then
            Call DataExport(item)
        Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the [`ItemsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.itemsselected) property which is a collection of indexes corresponding of the items selected in the list box control.

You can then use each index to acquire the appropriate item from the [`ItemData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.itemdata) collection.

For example:

```
Private Sub cmdBegin_Click()
    Dim i
    With Me.lstSmartSheet
        For Each i In .ItemsSelected
            Call DataExport(.ItemData(i))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Here, within the [`For Each`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) loop, the variant variable `i` is successively assigned each index within the collection of indexes of selected items.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you explain how the program knows that the variable "i" is the name of the selected item? When working with variables, my first thought is to assign them a value, but we aren't doing that here (at least not how we do it traditionally).

Comment: You're welcome. Within the `For Each` loop, the variable `i` is successively assigned each index within the collection of indexes of selected items. You may wish to view it as a 'placeholder', representing the item processed at each iteration of the loop.